# Slack & Python to run slack to open a specific chat (from 3dsmax and Maya)

Tags: python, maya, slack, 3dsmax

Using slack : https://slack.com/

With Python in 3dsmax and Maya then already found a smart way to run slack from both platform:

```
import subprocess
import getpass
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\' + getpass.getuser() + '\\AppData\\Local\\slack\\slack.exe'])
```

But then wondering how to target a specific chat to the same time?

It's mainly for tool support if the user would like some assistance in office, then he directly access to my chat.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Alright a colleague gave me a lead to the Slack deep-linking documentation :

https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking#open_a_direct_message

```
import os
os.startfile('slack://user?team=XXXXXXX&id=YYYYYYY')
```

XXXXXXX and YYYYYYY should be your teamID then the userID.

Cheers! :)

Comment: You might want to try the [slacker](https://github.com/os/slacker) python module for direct posts or automated bug reports

Comment: Hmm well, those tools are for artist, then I wouldn't like to ask them to install more python module... Was looking for a pretty simple integration.
The method I answered to the top work a charm!

Thank you :)